# is there a way to receive messages from service bus from an angular app without signalR?

Tags: angular, azure-servicebus-queues

We planned in our app to post some messages from our backend (for some very long process we really can't just wait) to an azure service bus and consume it from our front end.

Is there a way to do that directly from the front or do we have to implement some signalR solution with some intermediary steps at the back?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to send an event with/without some data to the front end when processing is complete. Correct me if I am wrong.

Typical approaches are:

(1) Do what you normally do

(2) Use HTML5 server sent events

(3) Use socket.io (if you have a Node server which prob you don't) - essentially websockets on speed

(4) Use websockets to send the data from server to client

(5) Provide an API endpoint/URL which Angular can poll to see if the data is ready (old school)

Hope this answers your question. Sadly, I know nothing about Azure.

Comment: thx for your answer, yes we have an angular front and an asp.net core back, connected with many azure services and we apparently thought wrong that the angular app could directly consume the service bus queue, hopefully there's a way ….

Comment: angular runs on Node, maybe there's an npm package to do this which you could use in your Angular app. On prod, when Node is not there, it should have bundled any code it needs.

Comment: Heres one that might help ... https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-sb ... should work if you use it in your Angular app (although I repeat I know nothing on Azure)

Comment: On second thoughts, seeing the connection string ... "amqp://user:pass@localhost:5672" ... its prob just a server side only Node package, or maybe it is connecting to a remote host

Comment: looks promising thanks (it's late though where I live I'll check on that tomorrow)